# Shopping cart ajax quantity display wrong when changing so fast.

Tags: cart, ajax

I'm working with ajax in shopping cart magento. Here is my website: http://sites.magebuzz.com/wholesalersdirect/checkout/cart/.

When I change the quantity of each item by clicking on up or down button, I use ajax to update price, subtotal ... but when I clicking so fast, it will display wrong. So anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ajax requests aren't finished processing and therefore lock one another out when your are cycling the quantity and requesting the prices.  Personally i'd disable the button during the processing time to ensure that this doesn't happen.  Additionally i'd also grey out the button to show the user that their continuous clicks (and the button) aren't functional.  When the ajax request successfully returns, i'd renable and ungrey the button.